# Does type erasure of Java Generics cause full type casting?

Tags: java, performance, generics

I know that when a Java compiler compiles a generic type, it performs Type erasure and removes all references to the generic from the code and my `ArrayList<Cheesecake>` becomes just an `ArrayList`.

The question that I don't have a clear answer for is, whether this lack of a type (and therefore mandatory Type-casting) causes slow down.  In order words, if I am using the standard Java compiler and the standard JVM 1.7 from Oracle:

- Does the bytecode include a type cast?
- If yes, does it include a run-time check to check if its the correct type?
- Does the conversion itself take a non-trivial amount of time?
- Would making my own `CheesecakeList` class that looks identical to `ArrayList`, just with all of the `Object`s turned to `Cheesecake`s would I gain anything (again just a hypothetical and I am not interested in any side effects of having a larger binary because of more classes nor the duplication in my code).

I am not interested in any other problems that type erasure causes, just a simple answer from someone who understand the JVM better than I do.

I am most interested in the cost in this example:

```
List<Cheesecake> list = new ArrayList<Cheesecake>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
   // I know this gets converted to ((Cheesecake)list.get(i)).at(me)
   list.get(i).eat(me); 
}
```

Is that cast inside the loop expensive and/or significant as compared to:

```
CheesecakeList list = new CheesecakeList();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
   //where the return of list.get() is a Cheesecake, therefore there is no casting.
   list.get(i).eat(me); 
}
```

DISCLAIMER: This is mostly a question of academic curiosity.  I really doubt that there is any significant performance issues with the type cast and removing the need for them wouldn't be even one of the top 5 things I would do if I found a performance bug in my code.  If you are reading this because you DO have a performance issue do yourself a favor and start up a profiler and find out where the bottle neck is.  If you really believe its in the type-casting, only then should you try and optimize it somehow.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The short story: Yes, there is a type check. Here's the proof -

Given the following classes:

```
// Let's define a generic class.
public class Cell<T> {
  public void set(T t) { this.t = t; }
  public T get() { return t; }
  
  private T t;
}

public class A {

  static Cell<String> cell = new Cell<String>();  // Instantiate it.
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Now, let's use it.
    cell.set("a");
    String s = cell.get(); 
    System.out.println(s);
  }  
}
```

The bytecode that `A.main()` is compiled into (decompiled via `javap -c A.class`) is as follows:

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
Code:
   0: getstatic     #20                 // Field cell:Lp2/Cell;
   3: ldc           #22                 // String a
   5: invokevirtual #24                 // Method p2/Cell.set:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
   8: getstatic     #20                 // Field cell:Lp2/Cell;
  11: invokevirtual #30                 // Method p2/Cell.get:()Ljava/lang/Object;
  14: checkcast     #34                 // class java/lang/String
  17: astore_1      
  18: getstatic     #36                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  21: aload_1       
  22: invokevirtual #42                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  25: return        
}
```

As you can in offset `14`, the result of `cell.get()` is type checked to verify that is indeed a string:

```
 14: checkcast     #34                 // class java/lang/String
```

This does incur some runtime penalty. However, as the JVM is pretty well optimized, the effect of this is likely to be minimal.

The longer story:

How would you go about implementing such a `CheesecakeList` class? Wouldn't this class define an array to hold the elements? Be advised that every assignment to an array incurs a hidden type check. So you won't gain as much as you think (although it is likely that your program will perform more read operations than write operations so a `Cheesecake[]` array will give you something).

Bottom line: don't optimize prematurely.

A final comment. People often think that type erasure means that `Cell<String>` is compiled into `Cell<Object>`. That's not true. The erasure is applied only to the definition of the generic class/method. It is not applied to the usage sites of these classes/methods.

In other words, the class `Cell<T>` is compiled as if it were written as `Cell<Object>`. If `T` has an upper bound (say `Number`) then it is compiled into `Cell<Number>`. In other places in the code, typically variables/parameters whose type is an instantiation of the `Cell` class (such as `Cell<String> myCell`), the erasure is not applied. The fact that `myCell` is of type `Cell<String>` is kept in the classfile. This allows the compiler to type check the program correctly.

Comment: *"Bottom line: don't optimize prematurely."* This. +1

Comment: This was a purely educational question.  But your line saying that the typecast is there and that the JVM handles those really well, were the two main things I wanted to get from this question.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the runtime check is one that the CPU's branch prediction is going to be able to handle very easily, which will further improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

The type-checking is done at compile-time.  If you do this:

```
List<Cheesecake> list = new ArrayList<Cheesecake>();
```

then the generic types can be checked at compile-time.  This erases to:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

which is no different to any other up-cast (e.g. `Object o = new Integer(5);`).

Comment: I get that, what I don't get is how much of a cost that is.  Also, when I do `list.get(0).Eat(me)` it would have to compile to `((Cheesecake)list.get(0)).Eat(me)` is that cast (which could/would most likely happen in a loop) significant

Comment: I'm not sure what the cost is either (I would guess zero-cost for up-casts).  But it's certainly no more expensive than `Object o = new Integer(5);`.

Comment: Even if there is a cost it heavily outweighs the runtime exceptions you might get when not using generics

Comment: But that second example is interesting, because you're right, that has an implicit down-cast.  I don't know how that's handled.

Comment: The virtual method dispatch is likely to cost more. It's all heavily optimised. An advantage of erasure of runtime types is that the "generic" object doesn't need to carry around as much type information.

Comment: @JamesJ.ReganIV: However, I think the down-cast cost is unavoidable.  Because the compiler/JVM doesn't know whether you've down something grim (but perfectly legal) like: `List<Cheesecake> list = (List<Cheesecake>)(List)new ArrayList<BarOfSoap>(); list.get(0).eat();`.

Comment: My god Oli, I have rarely seen a line of code like that.  If some does this in the real world and hell breaks loose in the support department, it is on him and his code reviewer!!

Comment: @tom: Sure, that's an extreme example ;)

Comment: But I think that for your example you need to explicitly add an annotation to ignore rawtypes giving already a hint to the developer...  I don't think the compiler would accept that as is.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the bytecode include a type cast?

Yes. Type erasure is described briefly in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

> If yes, does it include a run-time check to check if its the correct type?

No. The type safety is guaranteed at compile time as long as you do not have any warnings.
However there are some *bridge methods* used as described in the tutorial above

[**Edit:** To clarify "No" means that there is no *additional* runtime check that is inserted by the compiler because of using generics. Any runtime check during casting is still performed]

> Does the conversion itself take a non-trivial amount of time?

By conversion do you mean the casting? If yes, then this would be the case even if you didn't have generics

> Would making my own `CheesecakeList` class that looks identical to `ArrayList`, ...

In general this is not a simple question to answer and certainly not without taking other factors into account. First of all we are not talking about generics anymore. You are asking if a specialized class would be faster than an `ArrayList`. *Hypothetically* yes, having a special class that would avoid casting should be faster. But the real question is **should you be concerned about it**?

To answer the last question you have to be specific. Every case is different. For example how many objects are we talking about? Millions? Repeated calls? Is the extra time noticable in the program's performance? Have you timed it? How do we expect our data to expand in the future? etc etc

Also do not forget that compilers evolve. A future version may have an optimization that would automatically fix a performance issue (if you can live with it, that is), while if you stick with a code base that becomes useless it will probably stay with the project for as long as it lives.

So my advice is a) be certain that you have a problem in this specific area otherwise do not try to outperform the compiler or the language itself b) time your code, set some standards of what do you want to achieve (e.g. how much delay is acceptable, what I have to gain etc) and c) proceed only if you feel confident that you are on the right track. Nobody can tell you that.

Hope that helps

Comment: `No. The type safety is guaranteed at compile time as long as you do not have any warnings.` It's not from the JVM's perspective, so the JVM has to check at runtime. The JVM doesn't know whether that cast came from a well-checked generic, an unsafe generic (warnings suppressed), a raw form, or somebody writing bytecode in a hex editor. It doesn't know, and therefore has to assume that type safety is not guaranteed.

Comment: @yshavit Hmmm I am not sure what you mean. As long as you don't have any warnings at compile time, the compiler has made sure that all generic types are well-checked. The JVM only needs to take whatever actions it takes in a usual cast scenario. It does not have to perform an additional check

Comment: The JVM doesn't know anything about the Java language. All it knows about is bytecode. Furthermore, it is required to throw a `ClassCastException` whenever an improper cast is performed. Unless it can prove that the cast will work based on the bytecode (and it may do that, I'm not sure -- but that wouldn't have to do with the compile-time safety, since that information was erased at compile time), it needs to check at runtime.

Comment: @yshavit I think I understand your objection. You are refering to the runtime check that is performed during the cast while I am talking about any _additional_ check caused by generics usage. I agree though it is not clear which of the two cases the OP asks about. I will update my answer to clarify that

Answer (score 0):

If you took the JDK source code for `ArrayList`, and you cloned it into `CheesecakeList`, and changed all the `Object` occurrences in  `ArrayList` to `Cheesecake`, the result (assuming you did it correctly) would be a class that you could use in your app and require one less `checkcast` operation, vs using `ArrayList<Cheesecake>`.

That said, a `checkcast` operation is exceedingly fast, especially if you're checking an object that is of the named class and not a subclass.  It's presence is probably more significant for slightly upsetting JITC optimization than for the actual execution cost.